# What are the bit mask operations that I can perform?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I am using java SWT, which has a bunch of bit flags and operations I can use, but I'm not familiar with them.

To better explain, I have a style

```
style = SWT.A | SWT.B
```

Which basically translates to having style A **AND** B. I know that this is because

```
A = 0001
B = 0100
A | B = 0101 (bitwise or)
```

But I haven't played with bits enough to know all the things I can do, this is all I know

```
style |= A; // style adds flag A
style &= ~B; // style removes flag B
```

Do I have something like +0 at my disposal? For ternary operations.

```
style ?= question ? "+ style A" : "as is, no change"
```

I'm thinking maybe

```
style = question ? style | A : style;
style = question ? style & ~B : style;
```

But I'm not sure.

Anything else that would be useful?

Comment: You can probably do it without branching if you convert your boolean to an integer that's either 0 or 1. Take a look at this page: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html.

Comment: If you're looking for "as is, no change," then ... yes, `style` is indeed the value of `style`.

Comment: Why would SWT.A | SWT.B translate to A && B ? That makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe he meant it as "the style is both style A and style B" - but I agree the use of the symbol "&&" is unfortunate and/or misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also exclusive OR.

Exclusive OR (aka XOR) says in shorthand, **one or the other but not both**.  So if you XOR `0` and `1` together it will return a `1`.  Otherwise a `0`.  And don't forget that these bitwise operators also operate on `boolean` values.

```java
int A = 0b0001;
int B = 0b0100;
// A | B = 0101 (bitwise or)


style ^= A; // If off, turn on.  If on, turn off.

style = A|B; // 0101
style ^= A; // style now equals 0100
style ^= A; // style now equals 0101
```

You can also swap with it.

```java
int a = 23;
int b = 47;
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

`Now a == 47 and b == 23`

And lastly, there is another use for bitwise operators.  Defeating short circuiting of if statements.  Here is an example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 8;

// here a is true, no need to evaluate second part, it is short circuited.
if (a == 5 || ++b == 7) {
   System.out.println(a + " " + b);
}
// but here the second part is evaluated and b is incremented.
if (a == 5 | ++b == 7) {
  System.out.println(a + " " + b);
}
```

I can't remember every using it this way and it can cause difficult to find bugs in your program. But it's a feature.